# How to create a App like jupyter notebook with interactive programming?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, developer-tools

Now, i want to develope a application about interactive programming ,just like jupyter notebook ,but i know little about this aspect,can someone tell me some ways or knowledge to start develope this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stages:

1. Create a virtual environment for your application.
2. Create a virtual environment for running jupyter-cells of code.
3. Implement a mechanism for interaction between two virtual environments on a client-server basis.
   The server sends cells for execution to the client.
   The client executes the cells and returns the result to the server.
4. Implement the graphical interface you need for the server side.

The mechanism of interaction between two virtual environments can be organized as follows

---

`server.py`:

```py
# venv-1

import sys
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Connection


def read_write_function(conn_for_execution: Connection, conn_for_interrupting: Connection):
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                std, received_output = conn_for_execution.recv()
            except (ConnectionResetError, KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError) as e:
                print(e)
                break
            if std in ('<stderr>', '<stdout>'):
                file = sys.stderr if std == '<stderr>' else sys.stdout
                print('stream:', std)
                print('message:', repr(received_output)[1:-1], file=file)
            elif std == '<error>':  # error
                print('error:', repr(received_output)[1:-1], file=sys.stderr)
            elif std in ('<block>', '<read>', '<readlines>'):  # next block query or read input
                print('[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]')
                lines = []
                try:
                    while True:
                        line = input(std[1:] + ' ')
                        lines.append(line)
                except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
                    conn_for_execution.send('\n'.join(lines))
                    print(('' if lines else 'nothing ') + 'sended')
                    # --------------------- <!-- only to emulate "interrupt execution"
                    if lines and lines[-1] == '#interrupt':
                        print('[SERVER] Sleep before')
                        import time
                        time.sleep(3)
                        conn_for_interrupting.send('interrupt')
                        print('[SERVER] Interrupt message sended')
                    # --------------------- --> only to emulate "interrupt execution"
                    # --------------------- <!-- only to emulate "exit"
                    if lines and lines[-1] == '#exit':
                        print('[SERVER] Sleep before')
                        import time
                        time.sleep(3)
                        conn_for_interrupting.send('exit')
                        print('[SERVER] Exit message sended')
                    # --------------------- --> only to emulate "exit"
            elif std == '<readline>':
                print('[one line to send input data to client]')
                conn_for_execution.send(input(std[1:] + ' '))
                print(std[1:] + ' sended')
    except:
        __import__('traceback').print_exc()


ADDRESS = 'localhost'
PORT = 60000
PASS = 'secret'

print('#' * 42)
print('Address:', ADDRESS)
print('Port:', PORT)
print('Pass:', PASS)
print('#' * 42)
print('Waiting for a client...')

# --------------------- <!-- only to run the client app on the server side and prevent Ctrl+C crashes

"""
import signal
import subprocess
import os


def pre_exec():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)  # ignore CTRL+C signal in the new process


executable = [os.path.join(os.path.abspath('ClientSide'), 'venv', 'Scripts', 'python'), '-uBq', 'client.py',
              f'--address={ADDRESS}',
              f'--port={PORT}',
              f'--password={PASS}',
              stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL]
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    exec_process = subprocess.Popen(executable, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
else:
    exec_process = subprocess.Popen(executable, preexec_fn=pre_exec)
"""

# --------------------- --> only to run the client app on the server side and prevent Ctrl+C crashes


# backlog = 2 --> Two clients: one for executing code blocks and one for interrupting execution
try:
    with Listener((ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASS.encode(encoding='utf-8'), backlog=2) as listener, \
            listener.accept() as conn_for_execution, listener.accept() as conn_for_interrupting:
        print('Connections accepted')
        print('#' * 42)
        read_write_function(conn_for_execution, conn_for_interrupting)
except:
    pass
```

Run:
`ServerSide/venv/Scripts/python -uB server.py`

---

`client.py`:

```py
# venv-2

import argparse
import os
import sys
from _thread import get_native_id
from code import InteractiveInterpreter
from io import TextIOWrapper, BytesIO
from multiprocessing.connection import Client, Connection
from threading import Thread, Event

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='client.py')
parser.add_argument('--address', nargs='?', help='address ("localhost" by default)')
parser.add_argument('--port', nargs='?', help='port ("60000" by default)')
parser.add_argument('--password', nargs='?', help='password ("secret" by default)')
args = parser.parse_args()


if os.path.exists(__file__) and os.path.basename(__file__).startswith('tmp'):
    os.remove(__file__)


class Redirector(TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, conn: Connection, std: TextIOWrapper):
        super().__init__(buffer=BytesIO(), encoding=std.encoding, errors=std.errors,
                         newline=std.newlines, line_buffering=std.line_buffering,
                         write_through=std.write_through)
        self.std = std
        self._conn = conn

    def read(self, size: int | None = None) -> str:
        try:
            self._conn.send(('<read>', 'read operation'))
            return self._conn.recv()
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)
            return ''

    def readline(self, size: int | None = None) -> str:
        try:
            self._conn.send(('<readline>', 'readline operation'))
            return self._conn.recv()
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)
            return ''

    def readlines(self, hint: int | None = None) -> list[str]:
        try:
            self._conn.send(('<readlines>', 'readlines operation'))
            return self._conn.recv().splitlines()
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)
            return []

    def write(self, data):
        try:
            self._conn.send((self.std.name, data))
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)

    def writelines(self, lines: list[str]):
        try:
            self._conn.send((self.std.name, os.linesep.join(lines)))
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)


class CodeBlocksInterpreter(InteractiveInterpreter):
    def __init__(self, conn_for_execution: Connection, conn_for_interrupting: Connection, locals: dict = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.locals = locals
        self._conn_for_execution = conn_for_execution
        self._conn_for_interrupting = conn_for_interrupting
        self._main_thread_id = get_native_id()
        self._ready_for_next_block = Event()
        self._ready_for_next_block.clear()
        self._can_interrupt = Event()
        self._can_interrupt.clear()
        self._thread = Thread(target=self._stop_and_exit_thread, daemon=False)

    def interact(self):
        self._thread.start()
        try:
            filename = '<input>'
            symbol = 'exec'
            while True:
                self._can_interrupt.clear()
                self._ready_for_next_block.wait()
                try:
                    self._conn_for_execution.send(('<block>', 'give me next block'))
                    code_block = self._conn_for_execution.recv() + '\n'
                    code = self.compile(source=code_block, filename=filename, symbol=symbol)
                    if code is None:
                        self.write('EOFError. Code block is incomplete')
                        continue
                    self._can_interrupt.set()
                    self.runcode(code)
                    self._can_interrupt.clear()
                except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                    print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)
                except (OverflowError, SyntaxError, ValueError):
                    self.showsyntaxerror(filename)
                except SystemExit:
                    break
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)
        try:
            self._conn_for_execution.close()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self._conn_for_interrupting.close()
        except:
            pass

    def _stop_and_exit_thread(self):
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    self._ready_for_next_block.set()
                    received = self._conn_for_interrupting.recv()
                    if received == 'interrupt':
                        self._ready_for_next_block.clear()
                        if self._can_interrupt.is_set():
                            import ctypes
                            ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(self._main_thread_id),
                                                                       ctypes.py_object(KeyboardInterrupt))
                    elif received == 'exit':
                        import ctypes
                        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(self._main_thread_id),
                                                                   ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
                        break
                except (ConnectionResetError, EOFError):
                    break
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e, file=sys.__stderr__)

    def write(self, data: str):
        self._conn_for_execution.send(('<error>', data))


ADDRESS = args.address.strip('"\'') if isinstance(args.address, str) else 'localhost'
PORT = int(args.port) if isinstance(args.port, str) and args.port.isdigit() else 60000
PASS = args.password.strip('"\'').encode('utf-8') if isinstance(args.password, str) else b'secret'

# Two clients: one for executing code blocks and one for interrupting execution
try:
    with Client((ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASS) as conn_for_execution, \
            Client((ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASS) as conn_for_interrupting:
        sys.stdin = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.stdin)
        sys.stdout = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.stdout)
        sys.stderr = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.stderr)
        sys.__stdin__ = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.__stdin__)
        sys.__stdout__ = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.__stdout__)
        sys.__stderr__ = Redirector(conn_for_execution, sys.__stderr__)
        code_blocks_interpreter = CodeBlocksInterpreter(conn_for_execution, conn_for_interrupting,
                                                        locals={'__name__': '__main__'})
        code_blocks_interpreter.interact()
except:
    pass

if isinstance(sys.stdin, Redirector):
    sys.stdin = sys.stdin.std
if isinstance(sys.stdout, Redirector):
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.std
if isinstance(sys.stderr, Redirector):
    sys.stderr = sys.stderr.std
if isinstance(sys.__stdin__, Redirector):
    sys.__stdin__ = sys.__stdin__.std
if isinstance(sys.__stdout__, Redirector):
    sys.__stdout__ = sys.__stdout__.std
if isinstance(sys.__stderr__, Redirector):
    sys.__stderr__ = sys.__stderr__.std
```

Run **after** server.py:
`ClientSide/venv/Scripts/python -uB client.py`

---

On the server side, enter code block and send Ctrl+C.
On the client side, it is executed, and the result is transmitted back to the server side.

Examples:

1. Print to stdout:
   `[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]`
   `block>` **`print(42 ** 42)`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
2. Print to stdout and stderr, raise Exception:
   `[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]`
   `block>` **`import sys, time`**
   `block>` **`print('1', file=sys.stdout); time.sleep(1)`**
   `block>` **`print('2', file=sys.stderr); time.sleep(1)`**
   `block>` **`raise Exception('3')`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
3. Read:
   `[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]`
   `block>` **`import sys`**
   `block>` **`s1 = sys.stdin.read()`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `read>` **`<Multi-line>`**
   `read>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `block>` **`s2 = sys.stdin.readline()`** (or **`s2 = input()`**)
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `readline>` **`<One-line>`**
   `block>` **`s3 = sys.stdin.readlines()`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `readlines>` **`<Multi-line>`**
   `readlines>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `block>` **`print(s1, s2, s3)`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
4. Interrupt (`#interrupt` must be the last line of code):
   `[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]`
   `block>` **`import time`**
   `block>` **`for i in range(10):`**
   `block>`     **`print(i)`**
   `block>`     **`time.sleep(1)`**
   `block>` **`#interrupt`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `[SERVER] Sleep before`
   `[SERVER] Interrupt message sended`
5. Exit (`#exit` must be the last line of code):
   `[Ctrl+C to send code block to client]`
   `block>` **`import time`**
   `block>` **`for i in range(10):`**
   `block>`     **`print(i)`**
   `block>`     **`time.sleep(1)`**
   `block>` **`#exit`**
   `block>` **`<Ctrl+C>`**
   `[SERVER] Sleep before`
   `[SERVER] Exit message sended`